# How to create redirect for log in modal

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect, woocommerce, learndash

I'm trying to redirect this login button to a different page upon log in success. How do I do that without a plugin?

I tried checking the Woo Commerce settings and LearnDash settings and it does not change. I tried looking in the PHP file but am not really sure where to start.

picture of login modal

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter "woocommerce_login_redirect", which will redirect the user after successful login.
Follow the code below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect' );
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
    $redirect_to = 'http://www.example.com/my-account/';
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Hope this will help!